# How to filter webapp src/main/resources and see replaced values with JBossTools

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e, jboss-tools

I have a maven web application which has the file src/main/resources/appContext-ejb.xml file which has the *${version}* placeholder in it.

I want that placeholder to be replaced by the version of the maven project, so I 've configured the maven resources plugin to enable filtering of the file.

After compiling with eclipse I can see the file under the *target/classes* directory with the correct (replaced value).

Also when packaging the war archive the file is being replaced without problems.

My problem is that I want to use the JBoss Tools eclipse plugin to start my web application, so I create a jboss server, and add my web application to it. When I start jboss (from within eclipse using jboss tools) and try to use my application the piece of code which needs that file with the replaced value fails telling that *${version}* was not replaced.

Does JBoss Tools plugin use *src/main/resources* instead of the contents of *target/classes*?

How could I configure or make Jboss Tools use the already replaced file in target/classes?

I 've searched the web for this and I 've found a lot of information on how to enable filtering to web resources so that jboss tools takes changes on the fly, but I believe that that's not helpful for me because this file should not be used as a web resource because it shouldn't be served as web content.